# Google Chrome Autofill: How to Stop Bad User Data Input

Tags: html, google-chrome, autofill

If a user puts their whole address in the Street Address field and goes to use google autofill the information is just put into the street address field. The State or city is not filled out due to the user filling out their google chrome autofill incorrectly. Is their a way of stopping this from happening? Is their a way of taking the address from the street address field and sending it to its correct fields?

[image: Chrome autofill]

Comment: I don't think there is a way to fix this easily, not without a bit of AI (that will never be perfectly correct) to figure out how to break up the pieces. I've dealt this this kind of thing before. A lot of users are really stupid about filling in forms.

Comment: If your usage rate will be low, or the application makes paid-level support reasonable, there's the Google geocoding API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview